# What is a good way to remove duplicates?

Tags: java, oracle

I have a varchar column. It contains values separated by semicolon (;).

For example, it looks like

> 10;20;21;17;20;21;22;

It's not always 7 elements. It could contain anything from around 30 to 70. The reason they designed it this way is because the values are actually genome segments and it makes sense to enter or retrieve it collectively

I need to remove records with duplicate columns, so if I see another record with the same value as above, I need to remove it.

I also need to remove the record if it contains same values in another record. For example, I need to remove

> 10;;21;17;20;21;22;

because it's the same as the first but it doesn't have the second value, 20. If it's more complete than the first, I will remove the first one instead.

`1;2;3;4;5;6;7;` and `1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;` are dups and I'm taking the 2nd one because it's more complete. `1;2;3;4;5;6;;7` is also a duplicate. In this case, if they have 13 or more matched numbers and no mismatch, we will merge them so it becomes a single value `1;2;3;4;5;6;7;7;`.

I can scan each record in java but I'm afraid that it will be complicated and time consuming, given that the table contains millions of records. I was wondering if it's doable in oracle itself.

My final goal is to calculate the frequency that those numbers occur. For instance, if number 10 appears 5 out of 100 times, it will be 5%. The calculation will be simple. However, I can't calculate this unless I make sure there's no duplicates in the table in the first place.

Comment: This is a horrendous table design, and it's probably not worth anyone's time to even attempt an answer.  You should read about _normalization_, and get each CSV value into a separate record.  Your question would be fairly straightforward with a better table design.

Comment: Someone else designed it so I don't have an option. I know it's hideous. I'm also breaking the value into separate columns, so each record looks like this: full value | value1 | value2 | value 3 | etc... I don't know if it helps me remove dups though.

Comment: Andy, first split up the values as you propose to do. Make sure to add a synthetic key. Then use a projection (select) to order the values. Then you can easily re,move duplicates.

Comment: Further points of clarification required. Are there always seven elements? Are `34;;67;88;20;;67` and `34;23;;88;20;42;` duplicates of each other? If so, which do you keep? Is `;;;99;;;` unique if no other record has `99` as `val4`? Because it's trivial to remove the exact duplicates. The hard part is establishing duplicating strings which have exact matches and nulls.

Comment: Your question is as fuzzy as your table design.

Comment: From your description I do not understand what you are trying to solve. _varchar_ indicates your data is held in a database? Does you _oracle_ tag mean it is an oracle database? Java is an oracle product too. Are you trying to solve your problem in _Java_ or in _SQL_? _GROUP BY_ for example would remove exact duplicates.

Comment: @APC It's not always 7 elements. It could contain anything from around 30 to 70. The reason they designed it this way is because the values are actually genome segments and it makes sense to enter or retrieve it collectively.

Comment: @cmoetzing sorry for the confusion. I use java as the programming language and oracle as the database. I can remove duplicates inefficiently off the top of my head, but I'm wondering if there's a better way with Oracle

Comment: @Thilo Thanks. My final goal is to calculate the frequency that those numbers occur. For instance, if number 10 appears 5 out of 100 times, it will be 5%. The calculation will be simple. However, I can't calculate this unless I make sure there's no duplicates in the table in the first place.

Comment: Your Question is not clearly written, and likely to be closed. I suggest you put some effort into a rewrite.

Comment: *"It's not always 7 elements."* So are strings only duplicates when they comprise the same number of elements? That is, does `1;2;3;4;5;6;7` duplicate `1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8` ? Or `1;2;3;4;5;6;;7`?

Comment: @apc 1;2;3;4;5;6;7; and 1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;  are dups and I'm taking the 2nd one because it's more complete. 1;2;3;4;5;6;;7 is also a duplicate. I didn't think of this scenario so thanks for pointing this out. In this case, if they have 13 or more matched numbers and no mismatch, we will merge them so it becomes a single value 1;2;3;4;5;6;7;7;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note: This answer is a placeholder because the question looks in danger of closure but I think it will be worthy of an answer once all the rules are established.**

---

It's trivial to remove the exact duplicates:

```
delete from your_table y
where y.rowid not in ( select min(x.rowid)
                       from your_table x
                       group by x.genome_string)
```

The hard part is establishing duplicating strings which have exact matches and nulls. Merging rows makes the logic even more convoluted.

Comment: Thanks for putting together my question. I wanted to make it simple but it appeared that more details were required, so thanks for that. Now that you mentioned the 2nd scenario, in which I need to combine the data, it makes the problem a lot more complicated than I first wanted. I think I'll figure out a way to do this in Java as efficiently as possible. I think I'm going to close this post for now. Thank you for your time.

Comment: You're welcome. I think it would be possible to solve this question in SQL, but it will almost certainly take some gnarly logic using the MODEL clause or MATCH RECOGNISE. These are esoteric syntaxes which challenge even seasoned SQL pros. As you are comfortable writing it in Java that seems to be the better approach.

Answer (score 0):

The sql below is a solution ONLY IF:

- 1;2;3;4;5; is a more complete form of 1;2;;5
- All your entries end with ;

The request was tested using sqlite so perhaps it may need some changes for Oracle.

It expects a table "TEST" with a column "VALUE"

```
SELECT 
    DISTINCT VALUE
from TEST As ORIGIN_TEST
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT VALUE FROM TEST 
    WHERE 
        VALUE <> ORIGIN_TEST.VALUE AND
        (VALUE LIKE replace(ORIGIN_TEST.VALUE, ';;', ';_%;') OR
        VALUE LIKE ORIGIN_TEST.VALUE || '_%;')
)
```